# Is it possible to declare a boost thread globally?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

Hello I would like to declare a boost thread globally and initialize it later.
so:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
boost::thread t;

void some_func()
{
    printf("hello world\n");
}

int main()
{
    t(some_func);

    return 0;
}
```

It is returning an error about the initialization.

```
error: no match for call to ‘(boost::thread) (void (&)())
```

So how would I initialize it?

EDIT:: The reason I would like to do this is because I would like to spawn threads based on a condition. So in pseudo code:

```
    if (cond A satisfied)
        spawn thread_A

   if (cond B satisfied)
          spawn thread_B


         // Do some stuff

         if (cond B satisfied)
          thread_B.join()

     if (cond A satisfied)
           thread_A.join()
```

if the threads do not have global scope, then I cannot do this

Comment: You need to learn to walk before you try to run. Don't try to write multi-threaded code until you at least understand the basics of C++, including the meaning of **initialization**.

Comment: the console prints: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::thread) (void (&)())’

Comment: That error message is not about initialization. The object was initialized when it was created, at the top of the source file.

Comment: @MikeF. I tried that and It gave me the same error

Comment: sorry, I just edited. I meant to say I called t(some_func) and I got the posted error.

Answer (score 1):

The default constructor for `t` initializes the object to have no active thread. In order to fix this, you will have to perform a swap.

```
boost::thread(&some_func).swap(t);
```

or an assignment from rvalue (in C++11):

```
t = boost::thread(&some_func);
```

Comment: I get the following errors:  error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘boost::thread&’ from an rvalue of type ‘boost::thread’
        t.swap(boost::thread(&some_func));
initializing argument 1 of ‘void boost::thread::swap(boost::thread&)’
         void swap(thread& x) BOOST_NOEXCEPT

Comment: Hmmm... now I am a bit stumped. I have used the std::thread.swap in that fashion, which I had thought was based on the boost threads. In my case, I was not using a global, but instead a member of a class that was only spawned under certain conditions..

Comment: I have corrected the answer. You cannot invoke `swap` with an rvalue argument.

Comment: @AndreySemashev Is that a boost specific limitation?

Comment: No, that is pure C++. `swap` accepts an lvalue reference, which cannot be bound to an rvalue. Well, except some versions of MSVC, which is buggy.

Comment: @AndreySemashev Which explains why it works for me... I'll have to fix that.